# Can I put windows xna phone games on a IOS device?

Tags: xna

Im making a xna windows phone game.
Im trying to test it out but with the emulator.
I cant because it has motion sensing in the game.
I dont have a windows phone but a ipod touch.
Can I put it on my ipod touch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not without some work, most likely.  But based on [MonoTouch](http://xamarin.com/monotouch) there is a product called [MonoGame](http://monogame.codeplex.com) which claims to be an XNA implementation for other platforms and devices.  Your mileage may vary, but at the very least it gives you access to a community of developers who are trying to do exactly the same thing you are.